# Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am working on a Mac OS X application with Swift.

This is my first time and I thought it would be the same as it is on iOS.

So I got this error (in the title) on this code:

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit

        class LoginViewController: NSViewController {


            @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: NSTextField!
            @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: NSSecureTextField!
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            }

            override func viewDidAppear() {

            }

                super.viewDidAppear()

                if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") != nil && CURRENT_USER!.authData != nil
                {
                    self.logoutButton.hidden = false
                }

            }
            func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
                super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }


            /*
            // MARK: - Navigation

            // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
            override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
                // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
            }
            */


            func loginAction(sender: AnyObject)
            {
                let email = self.emailTextField.text
                let password = self.passwordTextField.text
                ...
            }
    }
```

What do I have to write instead of self?

Comment: This code is not enough, if you want an explaination about it, please give more code about your class properties declaration or the code around your emailTextField object.

Comment: Ok I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `self` is correct. Try using the property `stringValue` instead of `text`.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: NSTextField!

@IBAction func sendTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
  let email = self.emailTextField.stringValue
  print(email)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated code! Also remove the placeholder code and additional bracket. I.e. remove  `<#code#> }` in the viewDidAppear function.

Comment: And the brackets have to be there. If they're not there, there would be an error.

Comment: The updated answer still has an unnecessary closing bracket `}` between `override func viewDidAppear() {` and `super.viewDidAppear()`. Try deleting that.

Comment: I've created a gist with your code. I balanced the brackets and changed `text` to `stringValue`. https://gist.github.com/chris-pilcher/67f2a306315e3bbf6a40100884ce8968

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't have any errors anymore!